# How to specify a query using current date in the mongoexport?

Tags: mongodb, date, variables, mongoexport, isodate

I need help with mongoexport command using the currentdate variable.
Here's the current formula:

```
mongoexport --db=branchless_lampung --collection=logInfo --query '{date:{$gte:ISODate("2021-08-24T00:00:00Z"),$lt:ISODate("2021-08-25T23:59:59Z")}}' --out=/bin/dump/log_info.json
```

the problem is I would like to assign the date as the current date. for example:

```
mongoexport --db=branchless_lampung --collection=logInfo --query '{date:{$gte:ISODate(**"$currentDate"-1**),$lt:ISODate(**"$currentDate"**)}}' --out=/bin/dump/log_info.json
```

which resulted invalid ISODate format.

Please advise and appreciate your help.

Comment: The date format expected in the query criteria is that of _extended json_. So, you can use that (also, refer the MongoDB Manual for what is possible or not).